# python unittest - Using 'buffer' option to suppress stdout - how do I do it?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In the unittest docs [ http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main ], I see the following method signature described:

```
unittest.main([module[, defaultTest[, argv[, testRunner[, testLoader[, exit[, verbosity[, failfast[, catchbreak[, buffer]]]]]]]]]])
```

The last option is "buffer".  The docs explain the following about this option:

> The failfast, catchbreak and buffer parameters have the same effect as the same-name command-line options.

The docs for the command-line options [ http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-options ] explain 'buffer' as follows:

> -b, --buffer
>   The standard output and standard error streams are buffered during the test run. Output during a passing test is discarded. Output is echoed normally on test fail or error and is added to the failure messages.

I have the following demo code which does not exhibit the behavior that would be expected:

```
import unittest2

class DemoTest(unittest2.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_program = unittest2.main(verbosity=0, buffer=True, exit=False)
```

The output of this program is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

In fact, I get the same output if I chang the last line in my program to:

```
test_program = unittest2.main(verbosity=0, buffer="hello", exit=False)
```

What am I doing wrong?  (I tried using `unittest` instead of `unittest2`, but it made no difference.)

Comment: What did you _want_ to see? This looks completely correct—it's the output from the test suite itself, with no output from the code being tested. That's exactly what `buffer` is there for, and it's working perfectly. (In your case, it's also working trivially—your code doesn't print anything out, so there's nothing for `buffer` to buffer, which is why you get the same result without it.) If you wanted something different, please tell us _what_ you wanted.

Comment: I don't want to see any output at all.  The docs say "Output during a passing test is discarded."  I expect to only see output if a test fails.  Since I'm running this via cron, even a single character of output is unacceptable to me, since it will cause an email to be sent.  So the words "OK", for instance, should not appear.

Comment: okay, I understand what is going on now.  Basically the program will still produce output, just not the output produced in the test methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point is that [*buffer* option](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-b) affects stdout writing inside your tests, ignoring that of unittest2 behaviour. That is to say, you will see the difference, if you add string like

```
print "Suppress me!"
```

to any test method, this expression will appear on stdout, if you choose `buffer=False`, while it will be suppressed if you set it to True.

Answer (score 4):

As I explained in the comment, `buffer` just buffers the output from the tested code. This means you only get output from `unittest2` itself. It's working perfectly. (In your case, it's also working trivially—your code doesn't print anything out, so there's nothing for buffer to buffer, which is why you get the same result without it.)

If you don't want any output from `unittest2` either, you can always run the script with a shell command line that redirects to `/dev/null`, or import `unittest2` from a script that redirects `sys.stdout`.

But usually you actually want to *read* that stdout, not just discard it. Even if you don't want to log it anywhere, you want to check that the last line is `"OK"`, so you can send an electric shock to your programming team or whatever you do on failure. Otherwise, what's the point of running the tests via `cron`?

Comment: When you run a program via cron, you can set it up to send an email that contains the output of the program.  But I don't want emails to be sent if the tests are successful -- only if they fail.  I am now basically re-writing it to redirect stdout to a file and I'll then dump the file to stdout only if a test failed.  Thanks very much for your explanations.

Comment: @JonCrowell: I did exactly what you're doing a few years ago. But I suspect that nowadays, setting up a real CI system is easier than duct-taping one together yourself like this. (Plus, when you finally get to hire a real build engineer, he doesn't laugh at you.)

Comment: What is a CI system?  Any pointers to informative blog posts on the best way to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.  Setting up cron jobs for unittests in this way does seem to be unusually difficult -- I've just realized that I can't even redirect the stdout to a file -- it again only works for the output of my test methods, but not for the text produced by unittest itself.

Comment: FYI - I am the real build engineer :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration - I guess this is something to delve into later.  I really want to get my system set up to send emails from cron jobs today.  Done is better than perfect.

Comment: @JonCrowell: Right, sorry for not expanding the abbreviation. The point is, it takes months of work to do 1/4th of the job of a simple open source CI system, and it takes days of work to install and configure a CI and turn off the 3/4ths you don't want. As I learned the hard way, doing it both ways.